# Where is Controller for IOS Message input view

Tags: objective-c, ios

Currently i'm looking for a controller which ios used for inputing and sending message.(on the bottom of the message view)?

Does any one have ideas of this?

Thanks a lot!

Thanks Simon for your quick response! I am not sure if my words above misguide you. I am looking for a message controller looks just like the default message app in Iphone while inputing and editing. 320 is using a black box and i would not like to use this if it is possible.....

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [MessageUI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html). Inside that you'll find MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController that present standard messaging UIs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Three20 library if you want a standard style text messaging control.

Comment: Thanks Simon for your quick response! I am not sure if my words above misguide you. I am looking for a message controller looks just like the default message app in Iphone while inputing and editing. 320 is using a black box and i would not like to use this if it is possible.....